# Post returns 1364, Field 'ADD' doesn't have a default value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[THe error upon clicking the POST button on Djangorest Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmbXK.png)

The **serializer**:

```
class CreatePolicyBenefitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ('company','name','benefits','price')
```

The **views**:

```
class CreatePolicyBenefits(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Policy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreatePolicyBenefitsSerializer
```

The Policy **Model**

``
class Policy(TimeStampedModel):
POLICY_CHOICES = (
('life', 'Life'),
('health', 'Health'),
('home', 'Home'),
('car', 'Car'),
('vul', 'VUL'),
)

```
PREMIUM_INTERVALS = (
    ('one_time', 'One Time'),
    ('annual', 'Annual'),
    ('semi_annual', 'Semi Annual'),
    ('quarterly', 'Quarterly'),
    ('monthly', 'Monthly')
)

company = models.ForeignKey(
    'Company', related_name='Policies', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default="")
description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
benefits = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
category = models.CharField(
    max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, choices=POLICY_CHOICES, default="")
premium_details = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
policy_details = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
available_premium_interval = models.CharField(
    max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, choices=PREMIUM_INTERVALS)
icon_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
icon_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to=upload_policy_icon, blank=True, null=True)
primary_color = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
# file=models.FilePathField(path=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))
adminupload=models.FileField(upload_to=pdf_path,max_length=None)
pdfname=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = samplename

def __str__(self):
    return '[%s] %s-%s' % (self.id, self.company, self.name)
```

[Here the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb7EE.png)

Is it possible when I hit POST button, the data can be displayed on the form? Thanks

Comment: Can you show `Policy` model?

Comment: Does your `Policy` Model has a `required` field called `ADD` without any `default` value ?

Comment: @Kishore all the fields in the Policy Model is required. Should I add default to all fields?

Comment: @ErsainD. added! All fields in the policy model are required

Comment: Where do you have the `ADD` field? Is it inside of a `Company` model? Or did you remove the field from `Policy` model?

Comment: @ErsainD. Actually, there is no ADD field on my models. That's why I'm confused with the error

Comment: Seems like you (or someone else) deleted the field `ADD` and didn't apply the migrations to the database. Did you try running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?